# Confirm email address exists and is not already taken, using Parse and email Regex

Tags: ios, regex, parse-platform

I am at the part of my register process where I would like to confirm if the email given by the user exists and is not already taken.

So far, I have the regex set and customized to how I want it (I am limiting the user to a student email address).

```
- (BOOL)validateEmail:(NSString *)emailStr {
NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Za-z]+\\.[A-Za-z]+@[ace]+\\.[tamut]+\\.[edu]";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];

[self checkEmailAndDisplayAlert];

return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailStr];

}
```

I throw an alert if the email is not acceptable.

```
 - (void)checkEmailAndDisplayAlert {

if(![self validateEmail:[_email text]]) {

     [self.email becomeFirstResponder];

    // user entered invalid email address
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Enter a valid email address." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];


} else {
    // user entered valid email address
    [self registerNewUser];
  }
}
```

If I enter an email that does not meet the regex requirements, the proper alert is not shown, and I am still allowed to pass through the registration as a new user. What am I doing wrong?

Please don't hold back on any feedback, I am new to programming and this is something I need to know, no excuses.

Comment: Isn't your code crashing due to infinite nested calls. You are calling "validateEmail:" inside "checkEmailAndDisplayAlert" and inside "checkEmailAndDisplayAlert" you call "validateEmail:"?

Comment: Also, your regex is very wrong. An example of a match by your system is: `AbcdEfG.HiJkLmNoP@aeceaeceaaeeecccaaeeec.ttmmtmmaamtmtmauututuuut.d`.

Comment: Aha ! That may be the lead I needed. I will start there

Comment: Would you mind proposing a good regex? I would like the following format - kishon.daniels@ace.tamut.edu

Comment: Or explain why mine is wrong

Comment: Yours is wrong because you have placed `ace` within a "select one of these characters" block `[ ]` and then appended the "at least one, but potentially many more" identifier `+`. What you probably wanted instead was to just have `ace\\.tamut\\.edu`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `validateEmail` method, you call `checkEmailAndDisplayAlert` (`[self checkEmailAndDisplayAlert];`), and it also calls `validateEmail`. I'd delete `[self checkEmailAndDisplayAlert];` to avoid endless loops.

Also, try changing the regex to

```
NSString *emailRegex = @"^[A-Za-z]+\\.[A-Za-z]+@ace\\.tamut\\.edu$";
```

The function to check validity could also look like:

```
- (BOOL)validateEmail:(NSString *)emailStr
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^[a-z]+\\.[a-z]+@ace\\.tamut\\.edu$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

    NSAssert(regex, @"Unable to create regular expression");

    NSRange txtRng = NSMakeRange(0, emailStr.length);
    NSRange matchRng = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:emailStr options:NSMatchingReportProgress range:txtRng];

    BOOL validated = NO;

    if (matchRng.location != NSNotFound)
        validated = YES; // Match found

    return validated;
}
```

`^` and `$` are added at the beginning anf end of the regex pattern to enable whole string search.

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work unfortunately. It still allows the user to enter the app and logs a successful registration.

Comment: I think it happens because the regex is not limiting you to just one or a number of set emails. If you are just testing, try `@"my\\.name@ace\\.tamut\\.edu` and enter another email. However, if it is the behavior you are looking for, I would not use a regex. An NSDictionary would suit better.

Comment: You need to add `^` and `$` anchors: `^[a-z]+\\.[a-z]+@ace\\.tamut\\.edu$`. Otherwise, stuff like `!!!!a.a@ace.tamut.education!!!` would match.

Comment: Adding ^ and $ did work, it logs an error in the registration if I try to add exclamation marks to the ends of the email. I'm still allowed to pass through the sign up menu, so I must be dealing with a segue issue as well.